# select two values and display null for the second if it does not exist in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables table1, table2, table3. table1 has columns a, b. Table 2 has columns c, b, d. Table3 has columns d, e

```
Table 1               Table 2                        Table 3
a     b               c, b, d                        d     e
```

I need to match table1, table2 on b, and table2 and table3 on d. I need to display data in column 'a' in table 1 and if there are rows existing as a result of match in table2 and table3, then I need to display column 'e' in table 3 along with column 'a'. I can display null if no rows exist in the match between table2 and table 3.

Let me know for any clarifications or data. I'm using sqlite3, but exists clause works just like in sql it seems.

I attempted but could not write a proper query for this.

```
select a, e from table1 t1 join tablet2  t2 on t1.b = t2.b (and if exists?)
```

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html will help you understand joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an outer join, like this:

```
select a, e
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.b = t2.b
left outer join table3 t3 on t2.d = t3.d
where ...
```

If rows in any of `table2` or `table3` are missing, `e` will be `null`

Comment: thank you so much, I will keep this in mind for future references too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, E
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on T1.B=T2.B
LEFT JOIN table3 T3 on T3.D=T2.D
```